# Read pipe (C/C++), no error, but not all data

Tags: python, c++, c, pipe, protocol-buffers

In a C++ program, I want to fetch some data that a python program can easily provide.  The C++ program invokes `popen()`, reads the data (a serialized protobuf) and continues on.  This worked fine but has recently begun to fail with a shorter string received than sent.

**I am trying to understand why I am not reading what I have written** (despite no error reported) and how to generate further hypotheses.  Fwiw, this is on linux (64 bit) and both processes are local.  Python is 2.7.

*(It's true the data size has gotten large (now 17MB where once 500 KB), but this should not lead to failure, although it's a sure signal I need to make some changes for the sake of efficiency.)*

On the python side, I compute a dict of group_id mapping to group (a `RegistrationProgress`, cf. below):

```
payload = RegistrationProgressArray()
for group_id, group in groups.items():
    payload.group.add().CopyFrom(group)
payload.num_entries = len(groups)
print('{a}, {p}'.format(a=len(groups), p=len(payload.group)),
      file=sys.stderr)
print(payload.SerializeToString())
print('size={s}'.format(s=len(payload.SerializeToString())),
      file=sys.stderr)
```

Note that `a` and `p` match (correctly!) on the python side.  The size will be about 17MB.  On the C++ side,

```
string FetchProtoFromXXXXX<string>(const string& command_name) {
    ostringstream fetch_command;
    fetch_command << /* ... */ ;
    if (GetMode(kVerbose)) {
        cout << "FetchProtoFromXXXXX()" << endl;
        cout << endl << fetch_command.str() << endl << endl;
    }
    FILE* fp = popen(fetch_command.str().c_str(), "r");
    if (!fp) {
        perror(command_name.c_str());
        return "";
    }
    // There is, sadly, no even remotely portable way to create an
    // ifstream from a FILE* or a file descriptor.  So we do this the
    // C way, which is of course just fine.
    const int kBufferSize = 1 << 16;
    char c_buffer[kBufferSize];
    ostringstream buffer;
    while (!feof(fp) && !ferror(fp)) {
        size_t bytes_read = fread(c_buffer, 1, kBufferSize, fp);
        if (bytes_read < kBufferSize && ferror(fp)) {
            perror("FetchProtoFromXXXXX() failed");
            // Can we even continue?  Let's try, but expect that it
            // may set us up for future sadness when the protobuf
            // isn't readable.
        }
        buffer << c_buffer;
    }
    if (feof(fp) && GetMode(kVerbose)) {
        cout << "Read EOF from pipe" << endl;
    }
    int ret = pclose(fp);
    const string out_buffer(buffer.str());
    if (ret || GetMode(kVerbose)) {
        cout << "Pipe closed with exit status " << ret << endl;
        cout << "Read " << out_buffer.size() << " bytes." << endl;
    }
    return out_buffer;
}
```

)

The size will be about 144KB.

The protobuf I'm sending looks like this.  The `num_entries` was a bit of paranoia, since it should be the same as `group_size()` which is the same as `group().size()`.

```
message RegistrationProgress { ... }

message RegistrationProgressArray {
required int32 num_entries = 1;
repeated RegistrationProgress group = 2;
}
```

Then what I run is

```
array = FetchProtoFromXXXXX("my_command.py");
cout << "size=" << array.num_entries() << endl;
if (array.num_entries() != array.group_size()) {
    cout << "Something is wrong: array.num_entries() == "
         << array.num_entries()
         << " != array.group_size() == " << array.group_size()
         << " " << array.group().size()
         << endl;
    throw MyExceptionType();
}
```

and the output of running it is

```
122, 122
size=17106774
Read EOF from pipe
Pipe closed with exit status 0
Read 144831 bytes.
size=122
Something is wrong: array.num_entries() == 122 != array.focus_group_size() == 1 1
```

Inspecting the deserialized protobuf, it appears that group is an array of length one containing only the first element of the array I expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This...

```
buffer << c_buffer;
```

...requires that `c_buffer` contain ASCIIZ content, but in your case you're not NUL-terminating it.

Instead, make sure the exact number of bytes read are captured (even if there are embedded `NUL`s):

```
buffer.write(c_buffer, bytes_read);
```

Comment: This point is correct, but does not explain the output.  It the stream contains embedded `'\0'` bytes, converting `buffer` to a string via `const string out_buffer(buffer.str());` will cut the output at the first null byte.

Comment: @chqrlie: seems you're only registering half the problem I described: `char c_buffer[kBufferSize];` isn't NUL terminated after a read, so any garbage characters after it on the stack will be written to `buffer` by `buffer << c_buffer`; it doesn't just potentially truncate early.  And `const string out_buffer(buffer.str());` does *not* truncate at the first NUL (perhaps you were thinking of `c_str()`?).

Comment: You are correct., but your explanation is incomplete.  The OP invokes undefined behavior *and* may forget portions of the output.

Comment: @chqrlie: that's true - I explain what's wrong and how to fix, and not what all the possible consequences of the existing wrong code, as I assume from the OP's code that they'd already understand that.  But, suit yourself.

Comment: Indeed, how embarrassing.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You catenate each chunk to the output `buffer` with this:

```
buffer << c_buffer;
```

As Tony D explains in his answer, you do not null terminate `c_buffer` before doing, so you invoke undefined behavior if `c_buffer` does not contain embedded null characters.

Conversely, if `c_buffer` does contain embedded null characters, portions of the stream are stripped and ignored.

Are you sure the streaming protocol does not contain embedded `'\0'` bytes?

You should also read [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) although in your case, I don't think this is causing your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the link, which is good reading.  (You're correct that it is not at issue here.)